# Reduce verbosity of Tomcat Digester logger in log4j.xml

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, logging

From what I can tell, these obscure log messages are associated with the Digester logging component of Tomcat. Does anyone know how to reduce the verbosity of these logs?

The following debug messages repeat seemingly indefinitely with 100-10,000 lines in between messages, and has added at least 20 minutes to the start-up time for the application that I am working with due to repeated context switching (as far as I know). There is no trace of anything but Digester messages.

Does this obscure debug message look normal to anyone?

```
2015-08-19 10:59:30,607 DEBUG [Digester] - <  Fire end() for SetNextRule[methodName=addOperation, pa
ramType=org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.OperationInfo]>
2015-08-19 10:59:30,607 DEBUG [Digester] - <[SetNextRule]{mbeans-descriptors/mbean/operation} Call o
rg.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.ManagedBean.addOperation(org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.OperationInfo@
2f64a8b)>
2015-08-19 10:59:30,632 DEBUG [IntrospectionUtils] - <IntrospectionUtils: callMethod1 org.apache.tom
cat.util.modeler.ManagedBean org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.OperationInfo org.apache.tomcat.util.mod
eler.OperationInfo>
2015-08-19 10:59:30,632 DEBUG [Digester] - <  Fire end() for SetPropertiesRule[]>
2015-08-19 10:59:30,632 DEBUG [Digester] - <  Fire end() for ObjectCreateRule[className=org.apache.t
omcat.util.modeler.OperationInfo, attributeName=null]>
2015-08-19 10:59:30,632 DEBUG [Digester] - <[ObjectCreateRule]{mbeans-descriptors/mbean/operation} P
op org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.OperationInfo>
2015-08-19 10:59:30,632 DEBUG [sax] - <characters(

    )>
2015-08-19 10:59:30,632 DEBUG [sax] - <startElement(,,operation)>
2015-08-19 10:59:30,632 DEBUG [Digester] - <  Pushing body text '
```

This is the log4j.xml that I am working with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" name="stdout">
        <layout class="my.log.SyslogPatternLayout">
            <param value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %t %-5p %m%n" name="ConversionPattern"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="my.log.filter.DynamicLevelFilter">            
            <param name="useJmx" value="true" />
            <param name="baseLogLevelName" value="logging.baselevel.core" />
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender" name="syslog">
        <param value="LOCAL4" name="facility"/>
        <param value="localhost" name="SyslogHost"/>
        <layout class="my.log.SyslogPatternLayout">
            <param value="{%t} %N{loggingFeature}|%N{loggingComponent} [%D] - %p %m%n" name="ConversionPattern"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.mchange.v2">
        <level value="info"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="info"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="info"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="net.sf.ehcache">
        <level value="info"/>
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
        <appender-ref ref="syslog"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

The */tomcat/conf/logging.properties file has the following contents:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = INFO

# To see debug messages in TldLocationsCache, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = INFO
```

How are debug messages possibly getting in? I don't even want these logs to be here.

Comment: The message in question has a DEBUG level, and the root logger is set to INFO. Upon changing the root log level, the problem still remains. Aaaaanndd they deleted their comment.

Answer (score 1):

You want to reduce tomcat logging, is that correct? delete the logging.properties file. And from that appender, remove appender containing org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender. The entire one. That will disable your tomcat logging. Info also spits out lot of information is what I have observed.

Comment: No luck. I still get Digester logs after removing the appender, and the logging.properties file. Maybe the classpath is broken...or something.

Comment: You would have to redeploy. And check that you dont have logging.properties file in classes folder.

Comment: Yep, I redeployed and still no luck. I have no idea where these messages could be coming from.

Comment: I presume you removed the appender as well. Can you check in your war file by using any archive manager, open it, go in WEB-INF/classes/ and check.

Comment: WEB-INF/classes contains log4j.xml files, and no *.properties files. The log4j.xml are the same as the ones I listed in the question section.

Comment: But i told u to remove the appender...why didnt u do that?

Comment: I did, and I told you that I removed it. It's in the very first comment.